# Import spring boot application as jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

i import into a war application two spring boot projects as a jar dependencies.

When the server start in the console i see the message:
*2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath*
but it seems that only one application context is effectively initialized.

It's the normal behavior?
There is a way for load both application context?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That was my mistake. I didn't notice that in the two jars there was two @Configuration classes  with same name and when the application context was loaded the beans defined was overrided. Renaming one of the classes resolved the problem